# Using a BC3223 triac to drive a load directly

Tags: triac

I am looking at the [BC3223](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2006171232_BC-BC2223_C596509.pdf) which is quoted as a photoelectric thyristor(I assume this is actually a Triac=bidirectional?) and I was wondering if this could be used reliably to drive a resistive 230V AC 15mA load, directly. (with a max cold start inrush of 300mA).

The datasheet claims 1.2A RMS current rating on the output side which would make it okay, but there is no mention of max power dissipation and the way it's constructed with the 2 parallel triacs makes me wonder if it makes any difference which pins I use to connect the load on the output side? For example should pin 5 be left unconnected and just use 6&7? Or should I just parallel the connections on 6&5 to improve current handling capability and power dissipation.

[image]

Comment: The holding current spec is 25 mA worst case

Answer (score 0):

The load current is 0.9A to 1.2A rms, so if you have a small load, then maybe you could use this part. But typicaly AC loads are higher than that, and there are other problems with inductive loads that require snubbing.

A better way is to use a circuit like the one below where the opto-triac drives a larger triac that can handle larger or inductive loads.

[image]
Source: https://www.circuitspedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Solid-state-relay-circuit-diagram-825x400.jpg

Comment: Thanks! I am aware I could use a circuit like that but with everything considered, the cost approaches that of a small SSR which includes everything in one package, that saves cost on assembly. I was looking for a way to keep component count & costs to a minimum by using that photo-triac alone with a snubber. What concerns me is that the BC3223 datasheet mentions a holding current of 25mA max and I don't know if that's a limitation imposed by the max power dissipation which is unspecified or something else. Why would they claim 1.2A RMS if it can only hold 25mA?